# Questions about a recently purchased wok

Tags: wok, seasoning-pans

Recently I purchased a wok from a shop without asking too many questions. They mentioned that it needed to be seasoned, and I assuming, but not convinced, that this is a carbon steel wok.

My first questions is to get some information about the material of the wok. As can be seen from the images the material on the inside surface of the wok has these cracked ridges and is not the polished steel that I would have expected. The outside of the wok seems to be a different material, or perhaps is the same but just polished?

The second question is on the proper method to season a wok of this material?

[Wok pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgqBu.jpg)

Comment: Can you call the shop and ask?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think those are "cracked ridges"; I think you have a hammered wok.  The appearance is an artifact of how they are manufacted, by hammering a steel blank into a form or mold.   It probably *is* a carbon steel wok, as that is the most common material used for the hammering method as far as I know.

According to this article at The [Kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-season-a-wok-43491), you should season it as follows:

> 1. Scrub your wok in hot, soapy water and then dry it over low heat on the stove.
> 2. Turn the burner on your stove to HIGH and add 2 to 3 tablespoons of oil to the wok. I prefer peanut oil, but any oil can be used - sesame,
>      chili, or canola. Coat the wok surface evenly with oil by tilting and
>      turning it.
> 3. Heat the oil and keep the oil spread across the surface until it starts to "glaze" the wok - in other words, it turns into a thin layer
>      of film. Use a wok spatula to move the oil around and tilt/turn the
>      wok to move the oil as well. Be careful not to spill any oil that
>      would start a grease fire!
> 4. Let the wok cool and the layer of oil will harden on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

Your wok is cast iron with an enameled outside.

There's instructions [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNPe5-swL-k) for seasoning these kind of woks about 3/4 the way through the video.

Comment: That was a well done video, and perfect advise, would like to add that vegetable also works as a peanut oil substitute. Here is another good resource for those without video: [Seasoning a wok](http://how-to-season-wok.weebly.com)